# Parse XML from local file instead from URL

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, url

so after your guides i changed the code to this but the app just hangs...
whats the next step from here? getXML is called from

```
Document xml = XMLemailF.getXML();
```

.

```
    public static Document getXML(){     
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    // get a document builder
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = db.parse("/xxxxxx/res/xml/email.xml");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return doc;

}
```

this is called

```
public static int numResults(Document doc){     
    Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
    int res = -1;

    try{
        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
    }catch(Exception e ){
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

through this

```
...
Document xml = XMLemailF.getXML();

    int numResults = XMLemailF.numResults(xml);

    if((numResults <= 0)){
        Toast.makeText(contactus_email.this, "No results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        finish();
    }

    NodeList nodes = xml.getElementsByTagName("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        map.put("email", XMLemailF.getValue(e, "email"));
        map.put("line1", XMLemailF.getValue(e, "line1"));
        mylist.add(map);
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And by the way, the title of your question has nothing to do with the content anymore... This is definitely not the same question than the original one

Comment: i didnt know how to paste code in comments. i just want them to be parsed into a listview. everything is working if i fetch the xml from the internet. the priginal code provides string output but your part a doc output. i'm stack there... will repost the first question if i cant be helped for archive reasons. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get xml DOM from a local file? Do I understand right?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("/path/to/your/file.xml");
```

Or

```
Document doc = builder.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/resource.xml"));
```

Comment: thanx for the quick response. what do i replace? i'm a bit lost

Comment: Just replace "/path/to/your/file.xml" with the path to your file

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can

try something like:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

// get a document builder
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

//parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
Document doc = db.parse("yourFile.xml");
```

and look in the javadoc of these classes for more infos

Comment: thanx for the quick response. what do i replace? i'm a bit lost

Comment: this replace the whole first part. you can forget about the whole httpClient part. Once you have your document, you can then call numResults(doc)

Comment: when i try this i get Unhandled exception type IOException on dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); and db.parse("email.xml");

Comment: Yes, you need to surround the code with try/catch or throw the exception. if you develop in Eclipse, the "quick fix" should help you

Comment: ok done that, thanx for the constant help btw. what to i return? if i return doc i get that i cannot be resolved because of the try/catch

Comment: do you get any stacktrace printed?

Comment: what do you mean by stack trace? (i apologize i'm a noob). my current issue is that the returning doc cannot be resolved to a variable. i updated the code to the first post. any help appreciated

Comment: move the Document doc out of the try/catch. the same way it's done for the DocumentBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Here is method that uses [SAXPArser](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example) to read  xml file on sdcard

```
public static RSSFeed parseLocalXml(String filename){
    try {



        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();

        RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();

        xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);

        InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(filename));

        xmlreader.parse(is);

        return theRssHandler.getFeed();//this is handler that reads trough xml nodes
    } catch (Exception ee) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **application.getResourceAsStream("your file name")** like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(application.getResourceAsStream("file.xml"));
```